# Cambiar tipo de columna SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hay alguna manera de cambiar el tipo de columna en un SQL server?

He visto esto pero no me sirve porque no lo guarda correctamente

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/modify-columns-database-engine

El problema que tengo es que todos los cambios de texto me los guarda como char, entonces al hacer selects o bien me obliga a utilizar `replace` o sino me devuelve el contenido del campo con un montón de espacios tal que así 
`contenido                                   .` (sin el punto, lo he puesto para que se vea lo que devuelve)

Edito para decir que el replace tampoco sirve ya que me elimina todos los espacios. El `trim` no funciona en SQL server tampoco...

Comment: Haz probado con un alter table?

Comment: Sí pero no resulta: `ALTER TABLE [basedatos].dbo.tabla
ALTER COLUMN poblacion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL` salta este error:
`Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
El objeto 'df__basedatos__tabla__poblacion' de tipo objeto es dependiente de columna 'poblacion'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
Error de ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN poblacion debido a que uno o más objetos tienen acceso a esta columna.`

Comment: Puedes comprobar algo?
Da la impresión de que la columna de la que quieres cambiar el tipo, ahora mismo, permite nulos. Si le estás pidiendo con el alter column que a partir de ahora no los permita, como ya haya algún registro con valor nulo en esa tabla, no podría transformarlo... por eso tira un error...
Si es por esto y necesitas ayuda para hacer los drop y add constraint dime y lo vemos...

Comment: Salta el mismo error. De hecho si intento modificar la tabla desde Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, al intentar guardar los cambios que hago en las tablas (no los datos, si no cosas como editar columnas) me sale un mensaje diciendo que para hacer eso debería rehacer las tablas.

Comment: No te deja hacer:

alter table tabla drop constraint df__basedatos__tabla__poblacion;

Comment: ¿Que tipo de restricción es `df__basedatos__tabla__poblacion`?

Comment: siempre puedes hacer un back up de lo que tienes, y crear la base de datos nueva, con las modificaciones deseadas y volcar los datos del backup tomado

Answer (score -1):

El tipo CHAR te rellena el campo con espacios para completar su longitud indicada.

En las SELECTS deberás utilizar RTRIM(campo) para eliminarlos y quedarte con el contenido SIN espacios.

Sobre las restricciones va a ser más complicado. Tendrás que deshabilitar las dependencias (o eliminarlas), hacer el:

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN xxxxx VARCHAR(longitud)

para cambiar la definición en la tabla y después rehabilitar o recrear las dependencias que ese campo tuviese.